# How to verify memory checksum of the code in STM8S controller

Tags: assembly, stm8

I am using "STM8103F3" controller. I want to perform ROM test in my code, but i am unable to find the register, which can verify my "memory checksum". Memory checksum i can get my adding the "ROM" bytes, but i am facing issue how to verify that. Can anyone help me on this Issue.

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer:

This is not possible.

Why?

If the microcontroller had such a feature, it would not be able to do anything but simply adding up all bytes in the Flash memory.

If there are errors in the Flash memory, it would calculate the same wrong checksum that you calculated. You would compare your wrong checksum against the microcontroller's wrong checksum and only find out that they are identical.

What to do instead?

In automotive industry you will calculate the checksum before writing the program to the Flash memory (e.g. you use the HEX file to calculate the checksum).

Then you write the checksum you have calculated to the microcontroller's Flash memory. When calculating the checksum you have to leave out the memory area where the checksum itself is stored, of course.

To do the check, you calculate the checksum over the Flash memory (on the microcontroller) and compare it against the checksum that you have calculated before writing the program to the Flash memory.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs